# Does running a buggy function stops hole contract from work?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, evm

Does running a method in a contract that has a bug in it, stops other methods of contract from doing their work? I mean in other programming works , when a buggy method runs the hole program will crash(except if programmer handle that). Does this happen to ethereum smart contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a smart sontract, only the current transaction will fail if an error occurs. It's still possible to execute other transactions involving the contract.